# How to map a value in an nested array to a property

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to parse a json and get hold of value inside an array -

```
 {
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "name": [
          {
            "family": "Doe",
            "given": "Jon",
            "middle": "Smith",
            "use": "Commercial"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I realized that i have a one more array at root level so i decided to parse `hits` which is a list and then `name` which is another list. I am able to see entire name array in the response but instead i would rather want to see only `given` value that is mapped to `fstNm`

```
private String fstNm;

  private List<Map<String,Object>> name;

public String getFstNm() { return fstNm; }

 @JsonProperty("hits")
    public void setFstNm(List<Map<String, Object>> hits) {

        name = (List) hits.get(0).get("name");

        this.fstNm= (String) name.get(0).get("given");
        

    }
```

expected output-

```
{
"fstNm": "Jon"
}
```

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: @deadshot i have added expected output

Comment: did you try with `@Jsonignore`

Comment: @deadshot i just did and it ignores hits but how do i map the value from a field given to fstNm ?

Comment: does the code you posted is working?

Comment: @deadshot it is working but it is returning entire `name` array i would rather want only one value from that array which is `given`

Comment: are you trying to convert json to object or object to json?

Comment: @dadshot i am trying to convert json to object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217494/discussion-between-deadshot-and-jon-abraham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `setFstNm()` method as below

```
@JsonProperty("hits")
public void setFstNm(Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> hits) {

    name = (List) hits.get("hits").get(0).get("name");
    this.fstNm = (String) name.get(0).get("given");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have to have name be the same object type as hits

```
  private List<Map<String,Object>> name;
```

I think you can accomplish getting all the values of name by declaring it as

```
 `ArrayList<String> name;`
```

From there you can try to set name something like

```
ArrayList<String> name = (List) hits.get(0).get("name");
```

Then you can create a get method to get name and then access it in your setter like

```
 ArrayList<String> name = getName();
    fstNm = name.get(2);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i am getting empty value i.e. null